# Custom properties on EntityError

Tags: breeze

I've been trying to send some additional information on the [validation errors](http://breeze.github.io/doc-net/ef-serverside-validation-core) returned by the server-side `SaveChanges` method but `breeze-client` is parsing these errors and takes only the properties that the library is interested in. Is there a way to work around this behavior?

Comment: I _thought_ that the client-side error object had a way to get the raw HTTP response, but I'm not sure.

BTW, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @SteveSchmitt i think older versions used to do that, haven't had the time to go back and see when it changed but from version 1.7.2 (could be earlier, that's when i noticed) the entity errors are parsed and only the properties described in the link are extracted. my scenario uses the `errorName` property to send a message code to the client which is then used for obtaining an `errorMessage` that can have parameters. it's the values for these parameters that i need to send from the server in order for the client to format the message.

Comment: That's a good use case.  Please open an issue at https://github.com/Breeze/breeze-client/issues and label it "enhancement".  Maybe we'll add a "custom" property to EntityError that can contain your property bag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly implemented by @SteveSchmitt in [#42](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze-client/issues/42)